# Vernemq custom build ''micwy/vernemq:1.12.5-alpine'' failed to deploy

Tags: kubernetes, mqtt, kubernetes-helm, alpine-linux, mqtt-vernemq

Error while deploying vernemq latest version 'micwy/vernemq:1.12.5-alpine' in my kubernetes cluster:

```
Permissions ok: Our pod vernemq-0 belongs to StatefulSet vernemq with 1 replicas
Error relocating /vernemq/erts-12.3.1/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv: symbol not found
Error relocating /vernemq/erts-12.3.1/bin/beam.smp: pthread_getname_np: symbol not found
Error generating config with cuttlefish
  run `vernemq config generate -l debug` for more information.
```

Anyone help me to solve this?

Added VerneMQ Helm charts repository:

```
helm repo add vernemq https://vernemq.github.io/docker-vernemq
```

Then edited values.yaml to use `micwy/vernemq:1.12.5-alpine` rather than the official image.

```
helm install vernemq/vernemq
```

And Deployed custom build using helm installation on kubernetes.

Comment: Why do you think that you can simply swap in a different container with the helm chart?